Uploading to Google Lens with Share X?
Share X is a software allows you to grab a screenshot (along other features) and then upload it to Google Images. It does so through this link:
https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&tbm=isch
Here's a image showing it in the UI
Share X UI settings for Google Images upload search
Once you press to confirm it opens a new tab in your default browser, with image results from that search in Google Images.
Is it possible to do the same but replacing it with Google Lens OCR?
My intention is to add a new option to grab text in an image with Share X and the n upload it to Google Lens OCR text detection in the click of two buttons.
I tried with but none of them work (I'm not a programmer)
https://lens.google.com/search?ep
https://lens.google.com/search?ep=gsbubb&hl=es
